# WPF how do I simulate a waiting period

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF app I'm trying to simulate the idea of waiting for something to load. I thought I could do a `Thread.Sleep` in the following snippet but it didn't sleep for 10 seconds before setting to busy indicator to false.

What concept am I missing here about WPF and how can I simulate a wait time?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        LogonBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;

    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it in the constructor. you should try the `Loaded` event instead.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: What does “it didn't work” mean? Are you claiming `Thread.Sleep(10000)` doesn't sleep? Did you test it in the debugger?

Comment: Good point, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never call `Thread.Sleep` in the main thread of a UI application. It will block the thread and hence the UI.

You may instead await a `Task.Delay` call in an async `Loaded` event handler:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    LogonBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
}
```

Or

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += async (s, e) =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        LogonBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    };
}
```

Comment: I was doing the ```Thread.Sleep``` for temporary testing purposes, but apparently it didn't block it for me though. Any insight as to why?

Comment: No idea what exactly you've observed, but it will definitely block the current (i.e. the UI) thread.

Comment: In my code above, when the WPF window first loaded, the busy indicator did not wait 10 seconds to turn off. It immediately set it to false.

Comment: Sure, but it would take ten seconds before you see the window at all.

Comment: ahh, ok. I see (in 10 seconds)

Comment: What is ```Loaded```? Seems like there should have been an override or something like OnLoaded would be more intuitive.

Comment: Loaded is an event, and because it is, you can attach an `async void` handler method. You can't override a non-async method with an async one.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. And everyone else who answered.